# Plot sine function using radians with xlim and ylim

Tags: sympy

I would like to plot a sine function with xlim measured in radians:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric import sin

x    = sp.symbols('x')
eqn  = sin(x)
p    = sp.plot(eqn, xlim = (-2*sp.pi, 2*sp.pi), ylim = (-1, 1))
```

This blows up because of how I'm using pi. If I replace pi with a numerical approximation (e.g. 3.14), the plot displays correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the handling of `xlim`. Perhaps it's not been noticed because `xlim` is rarely used, with the x-limits usually being passed in a tuple along with the symbol itself:

```
sp.plot(eqn, (x, -2*sp.pi, 2*sp.pi), ylim=(-1, 1))
```

works fine.

Comment: Thanks. I filed an issue on GitHub. BTW, is there a way to also label this in terms of pi?

Comment: Not that I know: using matplotlib directly is recommended to have more control over the plots. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html